# The device need to be converted to Unified UserData partition - Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to install latest Cyanogenmod on my Xperia T. But I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

I tried to install it several times.

**NOTE : In my phone the microSD card is not detectable. So i cannot copy the zip and install it from SD card.**

Comment: Have you tried reading the message? Have you tried doing a factory reset? It's not a problem with the install file/method, it's a problem with the User Data partition that requires formatting.

Comment: I read the message.
Wiped all data many times. Still the same error.

Comment: It says to perform a factory reset, this is different to wiping data.

Comment: @bmdixon In cyanogenmod recovery, there is an option to factory reset( which is used to wipe all data), I have done this.

Answer (score 2):

You really should've read either the [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-t-v/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-13-0-xperia-t-t3415827) or the [CM Wiki](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Mint_Info) before doing any of this...

> Migrate to the one big partition for CM-13.0 :
>
> - (Optional) Backup all your data, applications, internal storage, ...
> - (Optional) Empty the internal storage with the old ROM or TWRP 3.0
> - (Optional) If wished, do a full Nandroid backup from Recovery
> - Flash the latest ROM zip of your device to start the unification
> - Read and follow the instructions from the zip if anything goes wrong
> - (Optional) Restore your Nandroid backup if you want to
> - Flash the same ROM zip for CyanogenMod 13.0

So in other words, simply flashing the zip twice back-to-back will do.

Also, ditch CM recovery - it's not required and pathetically weak in function against TWRP. That will also allow you to connect to PC with MTP and put the zip inside the storage before flashing, which saves time if anything goes wrong (you don't need to `adb push` again).

Comment: +1: *[...[ CM recovery - it's not required and pathetically weak in function against TWRP [...]*